# Recommend chunk/part size for AWS S3 Downloads?

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-headers, range

Part of our web site lets users securely download files. We use HTTP Ranges to let users with good browsers resume their downloads, since they can get pretty big. We are currently migrating to S3 and would like to retain download resuming.

I've actually got everything working already using HTTP_RANGE and this code:

```
// Calculate the end range
$rangestart = $this->iSeekStart;
$chunksize = 1024 * 1024 * 8;

// Start buffered download from S3
do
{
    // reset time limit for big files
    set_time_limit(0);

    $rangeend = $rangestart + $chunksize;

    $aData = $S3->getObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $key,
        'Range'  => 'bytes='.$rangestart.'-'.$rangeend
    ));

    print $aData['Body'];
    flush();
    ob_flush();

    $rangestart = $rangeend + 1;
}
while ($rangestart < $this->sFileSize);
```

My only question is, what is a good size for `$chunksize`? Too small and the download is artifically slow, but I also don't want to make it too slow by fetching too much data from AWS at once.

I can't find much information in the S3 documentation for what a good size to use is. Is there a good "best practice" here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think the reason there is so little documentation about an optimal chunk size is that there isn't one. Download speeds vary widely according to so many factors that the size will vary as well.

I would simply do some trial-and-error tests with the lowest bandwidth option (like a mobile device if applicable) and see what happens with a "binary search" approach. Go really big (but not absurdly); then if that fails, test with half that. And so on.

If you want something more rigorous, survey or determine your customers' download speeds if feasible. Then do some math to optimize chunk size for the average customer.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I did some testing and ended up going with half-meg chunks.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Good luck with your project!